# How to make white color background color of <App/> component in solid-js?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, solid-js

I created a solid-js application that I designed in tailwindcss. I defined in the `index.css` file of my application a gray color which will have to be used as background color for the various screens of my application. However, I would like the base `<App/>` component to have a white background color unlike other components. So I wrote an `App.css` file which I imported into the `App.jsx` file and where I wrote the following code:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    @apply w-3;
  }

  body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    @apply bg-white rounded-full;
  }
}
```

But when I load my page, I see that the background color of the `<App/>` component is still gray, so I wrote the following code in my `App.jsx` file:

```
function App() {
 
  return (
    <div className="bg-white">
    <Suspense fallback={<WhelpsLoader />}> 
        ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

but that didn't load anything to the background color of the component, so I modified my `App.css` file like so:

```
.App {
    background-color: #ffff;
  }
```

but it didn't load anything and I don't understand why because in my opinion the css code written for the `<App/`> component should have priority over the css code contained in the index.css file.

I also edited my App.jsx file like this:

```
import "./App.css";

   ...
document.querySelector('.App').style.backgroundColor = "#fff";

function App() {
  
  useNetworkStatus();
  return (
    <div class="App">
    <Suspense fallback={<WhelpsLoader />}>
      <AppRouter />
      <Snackbars />
    </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `.jsx` file.

```js
document.querySelector('.App').style.backgroundColor = "#fff";

// or for entire <body>

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#e1e1e1";
```

```html
<div class="App">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: I tried to test your solution, but I'm not sure where to put this in my App.jsx file, when I load I get the following error:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`but I know the error is from my bad use of this method. I inserted in my question the contents of my `App.jsx` file. Can you help me with sample code on how to use this. Please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the imperative API, use the style attribute on the element:

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";

function App() {
  return <div style={{ ["background-color"]: "orange" }}>My Application</div>;
}

render(App, document.getElementById("app")!);
```